# Sort array by dates in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects as follows :

```
let cars = [
    {"id":20,"mileage":41300,"make":"Golf", initialRegistration:"09/02/2010"}, 
    {"id":21,"mileage":51300,"make":"Passat", initialRegistration:"06/04/2012"},
    {"id":22,"mileage":61300,"make":"Audi", initialRegistration:"02/01/2018"},
    {"id":23,"mileage":20300,"make":"Touran", initialRegistration:"17/09/2013"},
    {"id":24,"mileage":10300,"make":"Polo", initialRegistration:"26/07/2014"}
];
```

And I want to sort it by `initialRegistration`.

I tried to do it as follows :

```
let sortedCars = cars.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a.initialRegistration) - Date.parse(b.initialRegistration));

let sortedCars1 = cars.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.initialRegistration) - new Date(b.initialRegistration));

let sortedCars2 = cars.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.initialRegistration).getTime() - new Date(b.initialRegistration).getTime());
```

But none of these attempts did not work. The results that I get is :

```
Golf - 09/02/2010
Passat - 06/04/2012
Audi - 02/01/2018
Touran - 17/09/2013
Polo - 26/07/2014
```

[Here is fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1588/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor and do something like this.

```
let sortedCars1 = cars.sort((a, b) => new Date(...a.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse()) - new Date(...b.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse()));
```

```js
let cars = [{
  "id": 20,
  "mileage": 41300,
  "make": "Golf",
  initialRegistration: "09/02/2010"
}, {
  "id": 21,
  "mileage": 51300,
  "make": "Passat",
  initialRegistration: "06/04/2012"
}, {
  "id": 22,
  "mileage": 61300,
  "make": "Audi",
  initialRegistration: "02/01/2018"
}, {
  "id": 23,
  "mileage": 20300,
  "make": "Touran",
  initialRegistration: "17/09/2013"
}, {
  "id": 24,
  "mileage": 10300,
  "make": "Polo",
  initialRegistration: "26/07/2014"
}];

let sortedCars1 = cars.sort((a, b) => new Date(...a.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse()) - new Date(...b.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse()));

console.log(sortedCars1);
```

---

Or by string comparison using [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) after reversing the date string.

```
let sortedCars1 = cars.sort((a, b) =>
  a.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse().join().localeCompare(b.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse().join()));
```

```js
let cars = [{
  "id": 20,
  "mileage": 41300,
  "make": "Golf",
  initialRegistration: "09/02/2010"
}, {
  "id": 21,
  "mileage": 51300,
  "make": "Passat",
  initialRegistration: "06/04/2012"
}, {
  "id": 22,
  "mileage": 61300,
  "make": "Audi",
  initialRegistration: "02/01/2018"
}, {
  "id": 23,
  "mileage": 20300,
  "make": "Touran",
  initialRegistration: "17/09/2013"
}, {
  "id": 24,
  "mileage": 10300,
  "make": "Polo",
  initialRegistration: "26/07/2014"
}];

let sortedCars1 = cars.sort((a, b) =>
  a.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse().join().localeCompare(b.initialRegistration.split('/').reverse().join()));

console.log(sortedCars1);
```

Comment: how we can sort by date-time like "26/07/2014 11:30 Am" ?

Comment: @rakesh use moment or some other library to parse the steng and then do the differentiation

Comment: .toString if you get .split is not a function Error. But it is not sorting anything for me!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Actually the date parsing was not happening correctly new Date("09/02/2010") will not work and will assume date to be 2nd sep 2010 hence it need sto be passed as "2010-02-09" yyyy-mm-dd

```
  let sortedCars = cars.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(new Date(a.initialRegistration.split("/").reverse().join("-"))) - Date.parse(new Date(b.initialRegistration.split("/").reverse().join("-"))));
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1590/

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting way is proper, just change the date format in cars array, make it MM:DD:YYYY, or YYYY:MM:DD it will work, because these are the formats that Date parse accept.