# Reactjs Sort date array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I want to sort date from the product array ( date is one of the field in product). Please suggest me. Am using reactjs.

Please find the code that am using.

```
render() {

          let sortedDate = this.state.item.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(new Date(a.expected_ship_date("/").reverse().join("-"))) - Date.parse(new Date(b.expected_ship_date("/").reverse().join("-"))));
          let sortedDate1 = this.state.item.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.expected_ship_date) - new Date(b.expected_ship_date));

        return (
            <tr>
                <td><input name="line_number" type="text" value={ this.state.item.line_number } disabled={ this.props.mode }  className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange }/> </td>
                <td><input name="requested_ship_date" type="date" value={ this.state.item.expected_ship_date } disabled={ this.props.mode }  className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange }  /></td>

                <td>{sortedDate.map( (c, i) => <div>{c.expected_ship_date}</div>)}</td>
            </tr>

        );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array by dates in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058681/sort-array-by-dates-in-react-js)

Comment: That is not working for me. Uncaught TypeError: this.state.item.sort is not a function

Comment: probably `this.state.item` isnt an array.